# Fatal Error: Function name must be a string PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

Can anyone help? I am getting the following error: Fatal Error: Function name must be a string in .... on line 120

Here is the code - it looks fine to me, but maybe a second pair of eyes? I will highlight line 120.

```
function display($name, $display_name, $id, $package_results, $payment_type, $before_percent_box, $before_price_box, $after_percent_box, $after_price_box, $min_price_box)
{
    LINE 120 -> $records = $mysql_num_rows($package_results);   

    if ($records > 0)   //If there are records
    {
        while($package_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
        {

        }
    }
    else    //If there were no records found
    {
        if ($payment_type == 1)     //If it is a PAYG
        {
            createPricePackageTable($name, $display_name, $id, "", $before_percent_box, $before_price_box, $after_percent_box, $after_price_box, $min_price_box, $records, 1);  //Create one blank table, 1 month
        }
        else    //If it is any other payment type other than PAYG
        {
            createPricePackageTable($name, $display_name, $id, "", $before_percent_box, $before_price_box, $after_percent_box, $after_price_box, $min_price_box, $records, 2);  //Create two blank tables, 6 and 12 months 
        }
    }
}
```

I have also includes the code leading up to the calling of the above function:

```
function build($name, $id, $memberid, $results) 
{
    echo "<div class='popup-column' style='width: 100%;'>";
        echo "<h3>Payment Option " . $memberid . "</h3>";

        echo "<p>Which payment options do you offer?</p>";

        echo "<div class='payment-options'>";
            $payment_type = 0;

            $display_name = $name;      //Get the name of the Payment Type
            $name = str_replace(" ", "", $name);

            $disable  = 'readonly="readonly" class="readonly"';
            $before_percent_box = '';   //Setup variables to hold whether a input box is disabled or not
            $before_price_box = '';
            $after_percent_box  = '';
            $after_price_box  = '';
            $min_price_box    = '';

            switch($name)   //Disable some input box fields
            {
                case "Split1" :
                    $payment_type = 5;

                    break;

                case "Split2" :
                    $payment_type = 6;

                    break;

                case "Fixed1" :
                    $payment_type = 3;

                    $before_percent_box = $disable;
                    $after_percent_box  = $disable;
                    $after_price_box  = $disable;
                    $min_price_box    = $disable;

                    break;

                case "Fixed2" :
                    $payment_type = 4;

                    $before_percent_box = $disable;
                    $after_percent_box  = $disable;
                    $after_price_box  = $disable;
                    $min_price_box    = $disable;

                    break;

                case "PAYG" :
                    $payment_type = 1;

                    $before_percent_box = $disable;
                    $after_percent_box  = $disable;
                    $after_price_box  = $disable;
                    $min_price_box    = $disable;

                    break;

                case "Commission" :
                    $payment_type = 2;

                    $before_percent_box = $disable;
                    $before_price_box = $disable;

                    break;
            }

            displayPackagePricesTable($name, $display_name, $id, $results, $payment_type, $before_percent_box, $before_price_box, $after_percent_box, $after_price_box, $min_price_box);    //Display the table with the prices
```

...

Comment: `$mysql_num_rows` is `null`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: You really need to learn how to read error messages...

Comment: Also, on a related note: the `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is possible to call a [variable function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), PHP tries to call a function named `$mysql_num_rows`. That variable isn't defined anywhere in your code and is `NULL`. So you'll essentially be trying to call a function whose name is *not* a string and causes  PHP to trigger that Fatal error.

Change that line to:

```
$records = mysql_num_rows($package_results);   
          ^-- remove the $
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a function name that starts with a $ sign. Remove it:

```
$records = mysql_num_rows($package_results);
```